# Creating Summary Statistics in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, grouping, visualization, summary

I'm trying to create a D3 chart that will utilize both summary statistics (min and max) as well as unsummarized data.

I have a CSV that contains a Job Code (which contains duplicates) and a salaryToMedian which is a decimal. I want to compute the min and max by Job Code.

I'm receiving the error `grouped is not a function`. I'm trying to console.log the maximum for Job Code 1000.

```
d3.csv("http://127.0.0.1:8887/myData.csv").then(function(data){
    var grouped = d3.nest()
     .key(function(d) { return d.jobCode; })
     .rollup(function(v) { 
         return {
           jobCodeMax: d3.max(v, function(d) { return d.salaryToMedian; }),
           jobCodeMax: d3.min(v, function(d) { return d.salaryToMedian; }),
           values: v
         }; 
     })
     .entries(data)
     .map(function(d) {
       return {
         JobCode: d.key,
         jobCodeMax: d.value.jobCodeMax,
         jobCodeMin: d.value.jobCodeMin
       };
     });

    console.log(grouped(1000).jobCodeMax);
});
```

Comment: What's the D3 version?

Comment: Isn't `entries().map()` an array?

Comment: One thing I see: You have `jobCodeMax` twice in rollup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: At the time of writing, the current version of d3 is version 7.6.1.*

`map` returns an array, but you try to access it like a function, i.e., with parentheses.

Also: [d3.nest has been deprecated in d3 version 6](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide), which is also stated [in the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection):

> Deprecation notice: Use JavaScript’s built-in Map, Set and Object classes instead of d3-collection’s corresponding methods. Use d3-array’s group and rollup instead of d3-collection’s nest.

But: No need for all those calls. All you need is [`d3.rollup`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#rollup).

> `d3.rollup(iterable, reduce, ...keys)`
>
> Groups and reduces the specified iterable of values into an InternMap from key to value.

This should do the trick (once you have stored your data in the variable `data`):

```
// ... get data into variable data ...
const keyFn = d => d.jobCode
const valueFn = d => d.salaryToMedian
const summaryReducer = function(values) {  
  return {
    key: keyFn(values[0]), // if you want to also store the key in the summary
    max: d3.max(values, valueFn),
    min: d3.min(values, valueFn),
    /* any other summarization you want based on values */
    values: values
  }
}  
const grouped = d3.rollup(data, summaryReducer, keyFn) // all you need is d3.rollup
const job1000 = grouped.get(1000)
```

I created [a playground example here on ObeservableHQ](https://observablehq.com/@neonmika/d3-rollup-example).